# How do I get the pg_namespace for a running query in Postgresql 12?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-12

I have a long running query I can see in pg_stat_activity.

How do I get the schema name associated with that query?

Answer (score 0):

There is no schema associated with a query; what you probably need is the setting of the parameter `search_path` for that session. You cannot find that for a running backend unless you are ready to break into the executable with a debugger. This is a sample session, if the process ID of the running backend process is 19525:

```
gdb /usr/pgsql-15/bin/postgres 19525
GNU gdb (GDB) Fedora Linux 12.1-6.fc37
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
[...]
Attaching to program: /usr/pgsql-15/bin/postgres, process 19525
[...]
(gdb) print namespace_search_path
$1 = 0x55cf69915880 "\"$user\", public"
(gdb) detach
Detaching from program: /usr/pgsql-15/bin/postgres, process 19525
[Inferior 1 (process 19525) detached]
(gdb) quit
```

In this case, the values was `"$user", public`, which is the default value.